# How to handle class imbalance in multi-label classification using pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, multilabel-classification, conv-neural-network

We are attempting to implement multi-label classification using CNN in pytorch. We have 8 labels and around 260 images using a 90/10 split for train/validation sets.

The classes are highly imbalanced with the most frequent class occurring in over 140 images. On the other hand, the least frequent class occurs in less than 5 images.

We attempted BCEWithLogitsLoss function initially that led to the model predicting the same label for all images.

We then implemented a focal loss approach to handle class imbalance as follows:

```
    import torch.nn as nn
    import torch

    class FocalLoss(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, alpha=1, gamma=2):
            super(FocalLoss, self).__init__()
            self.alpha = alpha
            self.gamma = gamma

        def forward(self, outputs, targets):
            bce_criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
            bce_loss = bce_criterion(outputs, targets)
            pt = torch.exp(-bce_loss)
            focal_loss = self.alpha * (1 - pt) ** self.gamma * bce_loss
            return focal_loss
```

This resulted in the model predicting empty sets (no labels) for every image since it could not get a greater than 0.5 confidence for any classes.

Is there a approach in pytorch to help address this situation?

Comment: Have you tried setting `pos_weight` in `BCEWithLogitsLoss`?

Comment: 5 images is an extremely small sample size. Collect more data.

Answer (score 7):

There's basically three ways of dealing with this.

1. Discard data from the more common class
2. Weight minority class loss values more heavily
3. Oversample the minority class

Option 1 is implemented by selecting the files you include in your Dataset.

Option 2 is implemented with the `pos_weight` parameter for `BCEWithLogitsLoss`

Option 3 is implemented with a custom `Sampler` passed to your Dataloader

For deep learning, oversampling typically works best.